# Failed to connect XCAutomation in Appium

Tags: automated-tests, appium, ios-ui-automation, software-quality

I try to connect my iPhone to Appiunm it connected but once I try to run the device or run the installed application the error message got as "Failed to connect XCAutomation" My iOS version is 14.4.2 and I use windows.
Is there any solutions. Find everywhere not sorted yet, PLease help. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gozN3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old version so update appium or appium studio with new version. problem will solved